# Encrypt/decrypt a string without traditional encryption semantics (low security)

Tags: c#, encryption

I want to encrypt/decrypt (or shuffle/un-shuffle) a string without any dependencies on specialized .NET encryption namespaces or use of salt, keys, etc. Literally shuffling everything in the string beyond recognition and then un-shuffling when it's needed.

This is meant for a "no" security situation where even if the user manages to get a hold of the file where the encrypted string is held and figure out the encryption scheme, they don't gain anything meaningful for this specific application.

What is the easiest, most straightforward way of doing this other than shuffling a character array using a pre-defined RNG seed?

Comment: very low security == no security.

Comment: @MitchWheat Questions edited to address your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XOR` every byte in the string with (length of the string `modulus` 256). If Mod returns 0, use some other known and fixed non-zero value.

I state this answer at the risk of security gurus coming back and saying.. bad answer.. don't do that.. leave it for us (security experts) etc etc.. But you already indicated what you really want is some form of obscurity, and **not** encryption or security.

Note - I do agree that this is **no** security by modern standards. Period.

Comment: Used a random number (constant seed) instead of 256 just to kill the pattern.